# How can I create this simple float layout?

Tags: html, css

**I have a task that supports older browsers such as IE9, so I cannot use flexbox or CSS Grid.**

I'm struggling with making the `.second` and `.third` have equal height as the `.first` div.

Here is my attempt.
https://codepen.io/abccba_123/pen/QWKMwpK

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.first img {
  background-color: gold;
}

.second img {
  background-color: cyan;
}

.third img {
  background-color: grey;
}

.container {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container article {
  position: relative;
}

.wrap {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.first {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

.second {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
}

.third {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <article class="first">
    <img width="1920" height="1080">
    <div class="wrap">
      <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.<h3>
    </div>  
  </article>
  <article class="second">
    <img width="1920" height="1080">
    <div class="wrap">
      <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.<h3>
    </div>  
  </article>
  <article class="third">
    <img width="1920" height="1080">
    <div class="wrap">
      <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.<h3>
    </div>  
  </article>
</div>
```

What I want.

[image]

Thank you!!

Comment: use table, not float

Comment: Thank you. I will try to learn about table. Normally, can I create webpage layout with table?

Comment: This page was made with a table: https://www.spacejam.com/

Comment: You can try to fix the height of images. And it will help you to make fixed height of the container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.cont {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

article {
  position: relative;
}

.first {
  float: left;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: gold;
}

.second, .third {
  float: left;
  width: 500px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
}


.second {
  background-color: lime;
}

.third {
  background-color: cyan;
}

.info {
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 10px 0 10px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <article class="first">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/1080" width="1920" height="1080">
    <div class="info">
      <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h3>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="second">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/1080" width="1920" height="1080">  
    <div class="info">
      <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h3>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="third">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/1080" width="1920" height="1080">  
    <div class="info">
      <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h3>
    </div>
  </article>
</div>
```

I've partially solved my own problem.

Answer (score 1):

You may also use a `display:table` reset ;) Understood by every browsers **and IE8+**

*(`.wrap` div removed , but you can use it)*

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.first {
  background-color: gold;
}

.second {
  background-color: cyan;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.third {
  background-color: grey;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;/* for demo */
  /* width:1000px; */
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: table;
  /* IE8 + */
  table-layout: fixed;
  /* IE8 + */
  border-spacing: 5px;
  border: solid;
}

.container article {
  border: solid;
  margin: -left:5px;
}

h3 {
  padding: 1em;
}

.img {
  vertical-align: top;
}

.first {
  display: table-cell;
  /* IE8 + */
  width: 50%;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <article class="first">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/118/536/354.jpg" width="1920" height="1080">
    <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </h3>
  </article>
  <article class="second">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/536/354.jpg" width="1920" height="1080">
    <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </h3>
  </article>
  <article class="third">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1016/536/354.jpg" width="1920" height="1080">
    <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </h3>
  </article>
</div>
```

Comment: That's awesome! It's easier than using table. But how can I make this second table align with the first one? I only know how to do this with flexbox. [Screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/npWitAa.png). I cannot not apply vertical-align to this div, if I display it as any table type, it messes up all the proportion.

Comment: what do you mean about proportion ? do you need just a background color or do you need images aside to fill equally the all height. please clarify,This is not about float instead flex or grid anymore.

Comment: this is what i mean about bg-color : https://jsfiddle.net/ws83rbmh/

Comment: Sorry. What I mean is I want it to align, have equal height as you say. This image describes my goal. https://i.imgur.com/nHgxj7k.png

Comment: i'm afraid it won't be possible, without a grid/flex display , or a really bad idea: position.  But , js can help you , you can check if right column article containers  is less height than left is , then reset height on articles to match first-col. (the code here stretches the left col if smaller than the right, but not the opposite :(

Comment: Oh. I see most website do this kind of stuff always use float instead of table.

Answer (score 0):

A simple table layout:

```css
img {
  display:block;
}

.first img {
  background-color: gold;
}

.second img {
  background-color: cyan;
}

.third img {
  background-color: grey;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container td {
  position: relative;
}
.container td h3 {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}
```

```html
<table class="container">
  <tr>
    <td class="first" rowspan="2">
      <img width="300" height="400">
      <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h3>
    </td>
    <td class="second">
      <img width="300" height="200">
      <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h3>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="third">
      <img width="300" height="200">
      <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h3>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you, after I add the width, it shows [like this](https://i.imgur.com/FwDk8zY.png). How can I make the table fill the gap? Thanks!

Comment: look at table-cell vertical-align defaut value ... it is middle, reset it to top ;)  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align